# Android 5.0.1 LG Spirit no user accounts

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, accounts

I'm trying to add new users on my mobile phone - LG Spirit - but I don't have section/button "users" in my settings. I have android 5.0.1 and I have read that new, or guest users can be created in android 5.0 and newer.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: My settings]

translate from up:
Applications,
default apps,
localization,
security,
accounts and synchronization,
language,
backup ,

I've searched a bit and found that "users" should be over, or under "accounts and synchro", but like you see I don't have it. How I can unlock this feature?

This is my software:

[image: IMG: Android 5.0.1]

EDIT: Model is LG-H440n

Answer (score 0):

Try using quick settings menu instead of settings:

Unlock your phone, slide two fingers top->down, click the small menu button in the top right, now under devices you should see users.

Did that resolve your issue?

Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: Hey, Thanks for reply. I've tried it and it's same settings. Still don't have "users"

Comment: I don't see the menu, so I'm shooting blind here, but maybe this will help: try sliding two fingers top->down so you see the status bar with quick settings option. Now instead of tapping the gear icon, tap the icon on the right of it, it should be a round icon, with a person symbol, this should link directly to the users acc management.

Comment: That's the point. I don't have it. I have like that http://androidphonehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/LG-Spirit-Notification-Homescreen.jpg
btw. this pic was found on internet